# python json dictionary direct access

Tags: python, json

I am confused why I have to use `.get('key') when trying to access an array of objects from a json file

```
req = urllib2.Request("http://website.com/entertainment/entertainment_news.json", None)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(req)
stories = json.load(f)
for new_story in stories:
    #Why can't I access variables using
    new_story.title

    #I have to do
    new_story.get('title')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that when the `json` module parses a JSON object, it returns a Python `dict` - which is a more suitable data structure in Python for the data at hand.

This means you don't want to try and access the field on it, but rather access the item in the `dict`. The Python syntax for accessing items of `dict`s (or `dict`-like objects) is:

```
dict[name]
```

So in your case:

```
new_story['title']
```

See [the documentation for `dict`s](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for more information.

The [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function allows you to easily get a default value (which is, by default `None`) if the key doesn't exist (normally this will produce a `KeyError`. You do not normally want this behaviour (it is generally better to fail out sooner and see where the problem is, than get `None` value and have errors later when you try and use it).

Also note that this is a good use case for the `with` statement, to ensure that the connection is closed properly. As `urllib2` doesn't support context managers by default, we use [`contextlib.closing()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) to make one:

```
from contextlib import closing
req = urllib2.Request("http://website.com/entertainment/entertainment_news.json", None)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
with closing(opener.open(req)) as f:
    stories = json.load(f)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to use new_story['title'], but if this key wont exist, it will throw you exception

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Lattyware's* answer: in order to be able to access the dict using `.some_attribute` convention, you can use a trick:

```
class Story:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

#...    
stories = [Story(story) for story in json.load(f)]
for new_story in stories:
    # now you can do it!
    new_story.title
```

...although it do it if you *really* want to stick with "dot" notation. It just brings another complication to your program (apart of many other drawbacks, like `story.title.somethingelse` will not work in this simple scenario without some recursive initialization)

You can also consider using [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html).

Comment: If I was to do this hack (which I wouldn't, but I digress), I'd probably do it by making a `__getattr__()` method that just did `return self[key]`.

Comment: You can also do `params = type("Parameters",(object,), dict_with_parameters)`